# Label and radio on the same line does not span the td width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for style.
The HTML is similar to:

```
<td>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="domain.alignment" value="R"> R
    </label>
  </div>
</td>
```

and the Css:

```
label {display: block;}
```

The outcome is as below:

[image: Improper width]

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things that I found. `<div class="form-group">` doesn't seem to be necessary here, and you're missing the `-` on `<label class="radio inline`>, which should be `radio-inline`. The following layout seems to work:

```
<td>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="alignment" value="left" type="radio"> L
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="alignment" value="center" type="radio"> C
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="alignment" value="right" type="radio"> R
  </label>
</td>
```

See the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/b7DwhHK0xR) for an example.